# FullCalendar fetching events from server not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fullcalendar

I am trying to fetch events from my LocalDB server and have them display on my calendar, but they aren't appearing.

I am using the following method to fetch the events.

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
{
    var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
    var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

    var eventList = from e in db.Events
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = e.ID,
                        Title = e.Title,
                        StartDate = e.StartDate.ToString("s"),
                        EndDate = e.EndDate.ToString("s"),
                        EventType = e.EventType,
                        Hours = e.Hours,
                        AllDay = true
                    };

    var rows = eventList.ToArray();

    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{
    var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
}
```

My calendar is rendered as follows:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/fullcalendar")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendar")

<br />
<div id="calendar"></div>
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next today' },
        defaultView: 'month',
        weekends: false,
        editable: false,
        events: "/Home/GetEvents/"    });
});
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This is in my web console:

```
no element found abort:1:1
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. browserLink:37:40278
no element found send:1:1
no element found send:1:1
no element found send:1:1
no element found
GET http://localhost:54802/Home/GetEvents/ [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 10ms]
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working'? Is there any error in js or on server side? What is returned from server?

Comment: The events should display in the calendar, but they don't, hence why they aren't being fetched correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not conform to fullCalendar expected output. If you see the doc, you understand that each events needs to have at least these parameters:

- title
- start

In your case the code should be like this:

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
{
    var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
    var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

    var eventList = from e in db.Events
                    select new
                    {
                        id = e.ID,
                        title = e.Title,
                        start = e.StartDate.ToString("s"),
                        end = e.EndDate.ToString("s"),
                        eventType = e.EventType,
                        hours = e.Hours,
                        allDay = true
                    };

    var rows = eventList.ToArray();

    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The first problem is, as I think, the name of variables for each event. This not match what fullCalendar is expecting.

With this new one GetEvents method fullCalendar should understand and print your output.

Comment: @JamesLloyd do you see any error in the javascript console? The ajax call to Getevents method is executed in your page?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but this still didn't work. Not sure what I need to do. I think I need to set up a repository and use the converted start and end date times but I don't know where to begin with this.

Comment: You have an internal server error (500) in your application: [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 10ms] Until you don't resolve this error you'll never see anything working on fullCalendar. Are your db.Events fields all not null? Please see what asp.net error says about